# Authlogic - Selenium issue

Tags: selenium, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber, authlogic, capybara

I'm using Cucumber with Capybara. I've got a set of feautures which are running ok when I use the default driver for Capybara. Now I've written a new feature which requires selenium (because it involves an alert() box). I installed the selenium webdriver gem, and I set selenium to be my default driver (for now, later I may change it to be the driver for some tests).

Now, all of my scenarios fail. All of them involve having an already logged user do some stuff. It turns out that no user session gets created. I'm using Authlogic for authentication. I highly suspect the selenium webdriver is guilty of this, because, as I've said in the beginning, when I use the default driver, everything turns out ok.

This is the step which involves creating a user which is authenticated inmediately (if one creates a user from the User model, model which acts_as_authenticatable, then that user get logged in by default. There's no need to create a new UserSession):

```
And I am logged in as "confirmed@email.com", with password "12345" and school with subdomain "subdomain1"
```

This is the step definition for that step:

```
Given /^I am logged in as "([^"]*)", with password "([^"]*)" and school with subdomain "([^"]*)"$/ do |email, password, domain|
  school = School.find_by_subdomain(domain)
  user = Factory.create(:user, :email => email, :password => password, :password_confirmation => password, :confirmed_email => true, :authenticatable => Factory.build(:employee, :school => school))
end
```

Notice that I never create a UserSession explicitly, just creating the user does that for me. Remember, this works with the rack-test driver, but not with selenium. Selenium just doesn't care for this newly created UserSession.

Can you help me? Thanks!

Comment: Please post the error message and stack trace.

Comment: Leonid, there's no error message. The problem is that when I use the default driver (rack test), all the scenarios pass, and when I use the selenium driver, no user can get logged in. It's like Authlogic stops working with selenium. My application needs its users to be logged in. If the scenario says "And I am on somepage", and that page needs a logged in user, a filter redirects the user to a public page. Therefore, my scenarios fail: the user can not do anything but access that public page

Comment: Please post the step definitions, where you set up user session.

Comment: @socjopata, I've edited my question, which now includes the step definition you asked for. Thanks